ArcGIS Pro shifting data
I have used ArcMap forever, making the switch to ArcGIS Pro but when using ArcGIS Pro, I have my data in WGS84 for continuity in the data across Canada but I make my maps in the UTM zone I am in for that specific map because it is to better square up the quarter lines. When I move a polygon to snap to a point it will snap but then shift to the upper right.
Is there a transformation or something that I should have on to not have this shift Or any other suggestions that someone might have?
ArcMap never had this issue.

I would go back to your mxd and look at the transformation you had set in the dataframe and then make sure your map in ArcPro is set to the same transformation.
